# Package and find non Python Files in a python package

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging

I'm fairly new to python packaging and I'm trying to create a command line tool so that I can send to client to interact with my service in AWS.

My goal is to have a command line tool to upload files that are in the folder `resources` to s3 that will later be used by other services.

It's my first time using setuptools for that but I'm seem to be lost at some point.

My project structure is something like:

```
ProjectRoot
├── MANIFEST.in
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── dist
│   ├── myscript-0.0.1.whl
│   └── myscript-0.0.1.tar.gz
├── pyproject.toml
├── resources
│   ├── artifacts
│   │   ├── code1.jar
│   │   ├── code2.jar
│   │   ├── api.keys
│   │   ├── package1.tar.gz
│   │   ├── install-linux.sh
│   │   └── confs.yaml
│   ├── recipe.template.yaml
└── src
    └── code
        ├── __init__.py
        └── myscript.py
```

I've tried to make setuptools add the files to the .tar package with the pyproject.toml with this:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "myscript"
version = "0.0.1"
dependencies = [
    'Click',
    'boto3',
    'botocore',
]

[project.scripts]
myscript = "code.main:run"

[tool.setuptools]
include-package-data = true

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src","resources"] 
include = ["code*"]
exclude = [] 

[tool.setuptools.package-data]
"resources.artifacts" = ["*"]
recipe = ["*.yaml"]
```

After that I try to install the wheel generated file with `pip install dist/generated_file.whl`, but I can't find the `resources/` folder anywhere during installation.

ps.: I also got a little lost if I need the whl and the tar package together.

I tried using relative paths to find the resources, but I saw they weren't installed in the sites_packages.

My latest try was using `from importlib_resources import files` but it also can't seem to find the resources.

I can't find the resources folder files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Starting point

With the given project structure

```
 <project root>/
├─ pyproject.toml
├─ src/
│ └─ code/
│   ├─ __init__.py
│   └─ myscript.py
├─ resources/
  └─ artifacts/
    └─ code1.jar
```

and by specifying

```ini
[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src","resources"]
include = ["code*"]
exclude = []

[tool.setuptools.package-data]
"resources.artifacts" = ["*"]
recipe = ["*.yaml"]
```

you'll get a wheel with following contents

```
 myscript-0.0.1-py3-none-any/
└─ code/
  ├─ __init__.py
  └─ myscript.py
```

The reason for this is that the only *package* found is `code`. A package is a folder with python (.py) files, and usually with `__init__.py` file (if not talking about [namespace packages](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/) which are a bit of a special thing).

#### What I would do?

- First, renaming your main package folder. You've called your project `myscript` in pyproject (so you would install it with `pip install myscript`), but then the file structure would imply that the *import name*  is `code`; so you would need to do `import code.myscript` (code being the main package). I'll change the project name to be in this example `myproj`, by changing the name in pyproject.toml and `./code` folder to `./myproj`
- Second, the name of the "package-data" to me says that it is data inside a *package*. The `./resources` is not a package as it does not contain any python files. If you add there an empty `__init__.py`, it will become a package. But there is another problem in pyproject.toml: your package should be found under a folder called `./resources`, but that is actually in root folder (`.`). Therefore, you should either change `where = ['src', '.']` (which creates new problems) or move `./resources` to `./resources/resources`, but you could also do it easier (third point)
- Third, you could simplify things by putting the data files *inside* you package (`./myproj`). That's fair more common practice, and also makes pip install the resources with your code, inside `site-packages/myproj`, which is nice (although, there are other possibilities). So, I propose these changes to pyproject.toml:

```ini
[project]
name = "myproj" # <-- this changed
version = "0.0.1"

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"] # <-- this changed

[tool.setuptools.package-data]
"*" = ["*.*"] # <-- this changed
```

and then the folder structure to

```
 <project root>/
├─ pyproject.toml
└─ src/
  └─ myproj/
    ├─ __init__.py
    ├─ __assets__/ # non-code files here
    │ └─ code1.jar     
    └─ myscript.py
```

That will then create a wheel with following folder structure:

```
└─ myproj-0.0.1-py3-none-any/
  └─ myproj/
    ├─ __init__.py
    ├─ __assets__/
    │ └─ code1.jar
    └─ myscript.py
```

Comment: Thank you Niko.
I actually don't like putting the files inside my src folder, because they are not part of the source itself. But it was the simpler solution for this, and in this case it might just work.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `data_files` for this. (https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#data-files)

> Each (directory, files) pair in the sequence specifies the installation directory and the files to install there. The directory must be a relative path [...]

This will install the `files` in the `directory` relative to site-packages or user install location.

Comment: Thanks man, I found that I think setup tools had deprecated data_files, but I tried it and it worked but it was harder to find the files

Comment: Looked it up - it is (Legacy) and likely not the best way forward, but the current guide at https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/ says

> The files listed above will be included automatically in your source distribution. If you want to include additional files, see the documentation for your build backend.

Time to update my project, it seems!